# A question about Feynman's 'Little Arrows' approach in "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

I have a perplexity regarding Feynman's famous "little arrows" approach.

To summarize and paraphrase Feynman as I understand him, he is claiming that we model the probability that an event will happen by squaring the length of the arrow we get by adding up all the arrows belonging to the various different ways the event can come about.

To take his concrete example, we calculate the likelihood that light will get from a source to a detector via a mirror by adding up all the arrows belonging to the various paths the light could take from source to mirror to detector.

I guess my perplexity here is about which question Feynman is tackling here:

a) Whether light will get to the detector AT ALL and

b) Which path the light will actually take to get to the detector.

Feynman says that the length of the arrow - ie the probability that light will make it to the detector - is determined mostly by the paths that take the light through the center of the mirror, ie the path where the angles of incidence and reflection are equal. Because that is where the arrows tend to add constructively rather than destructively.

I'm confused because Feynman seems to move back and forth between being preoccupied with explaining a) and with explaining b).

Is he trying to "explain" or describe why the particle has a nonzero probability of ending up at the detector at all? Or is he trying to "explain" or describe why we observe the particle to take the specific path it does between source and detector? It's unclear to me how these two are related, in terms of the Little Arrows game. It doesn't necessarily seem like these two things should be independent, but it's unclear to me how they are related.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! He does indeed seem to go between both somewhat arbitrarily in those lectures and/or that book.

To be clear, the little arrows are a lay description of what the technical of us call “complex numbers.” Feynman is deliberately trying to avoid describing square roots of $-1$ and such, by appealing to a geometric interpretation. Complex numbers are scaled rotations. They can be added together by this arrow-addition rule, or they can be composed together by multiplying the scale factors and adding the angles. The scale factor is variously called the number’s “length” or “norm” or “magnitude” or a number of other names, and the norm-squared is the probability in quantum mechanics -- or in the “little arrows” description you could talk about the area swept out by the circle that the arrow is a radius of.

Also to be clear, the correct interpretation is (a). We are calculating ultimately the probability whether the photon goes from the source to the detector and registers as a click. We are going to, at the end of this process, sum up over different paths and then be completely uncertain about which path it actually followed.

The reason that our language can sometimes veer towards (b) is that complex numbers have associative and commutative addition laws. This means that you can rearrange the additions however you want. So you can say “look all of the paths that go nearby this one way, they all cancel out and you do not get any contribution from around that path.” That in turn means that if you placed an obstacle in the way of those paths, absorbing any photon taking that path, the observed outcome at the end would not change. In that sense you can say that the photon “did not take” these paths. So if you have two media with two different indices of refraction—light travels slower in the one—you can find that there is only one path, the least-time path, which light “takes” and it constitutes a straight-line path to the interface between the two media, where there is a “bend.” What I mean when I say there is only one path is precisely this sense—between that source and sink you can put light-absorbers anywhere else not on that path, and the intensity of light at the detector will not be affected. (You may have to be a little careful here as if you were to place a slit at this one point which the light takes, if you start to narrow it to a few wavelengths wide or so, then you will start to see interference effects as you start to subtract paths that have nonzero contribution to the sum. This is sometimes called “single-slit diffraction” if you want to look up its properties.)

So if you can say “all of the actual contribution come from these three (or five, or six, or one) paths” then in some sense the photon only takes those paths because if you try to place a black wall anywhere else you do not see any change in the outcome. On the other hand if you try to obstruct one of the other paths you will probably change the interference of those three paths when you reduce it down to two, so those three paths really do count.

One last point, when he talks about the experiment when you erase a mirror in certain spots... in the [New Zealand lectures](http://www.vega.org.uk/video/subseries/8) that the book is based on, he says something like “I wish I had one of these which I could show all of you, they are really remarkable.”

You actually already have one of those, if you own a CD or DVD anywhere in your home. Just flip it over, the data track is one very windy concentric spiral groove that erases in a very regular spacing a mirror -- so the rainbows that you are seeing are precisely what he is talking about. If you are very careful you can even use them to see that incandescent lamps produce a full rainbow while fluorescent lamps only produce a couple of frequencies.